# Spring Boot, JmsListener and SQS queues on different accounts

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to develop a Spring Boot(1.5) app that needs to listen to SQS queues from two different AWS accounts.
Is it possible to create a listener using JmsListener annotation? I've checked that the rights are correct, I'm able to get the queue url with getQueueUrl() and setting the right account id with setQueueOwnerAWSAccountId().

Below is the code I've used for the listener that's under main account. Trying to use that for the queue on the other account, gives error

```
HTTPStatusCode: 400 AmazonErrorCode: AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue 
com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueDoesNotExistException: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version.
```

Queue reader class

```
@Service
public class QueueReader {

    @JmsListener(destination = "queue-name")
    public void messageReceived(@Payload String message) {
        // message received
    }
}
```

Queue config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class QueueReaderConfig {
    SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory = SQSConnectionFactory.builder().withRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1))
                    .withAWSCredentialsProvider(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                    .build();

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
                new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory);
        factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
        factory.setConcurrency("3-10");
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate defaultJmsTemplate() {
        return new JmsTemplate(this.connectionFactory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution to this? I am stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck with the same issue. I found a workaround by creating custom DestinationResolver and setting it in the "DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory" and "JmsTemplate".

Also, in the "CustomDynamicDestinationResolver" lookup the queue by ownerAccountId.

```
queue = ((SQSSession) session).createQueue(queueName, ownerAccountId);
```

Listen to queue by using the connection factory.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "MyQueue", containerFactory = "customJmsListenerContainerFactory")
public void process(String message) throws IOException {
```

A bit late but, I hope this helps someone like me looking for a solution.

Thanks,

Akshay

```
import com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.ProviderConfiguration;
import com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSConnectionFactory;
import com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSSession;
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClientBuilder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DestinationResolver;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import javax.jms.*;

@Configuration
public class CustomJmsConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomJmsConfig.class);

    @Value("${copies.processor.concurrency:5}")
    private String concurrency;

    @Value("${owner.account.id:1234}")
    private String ownerAccountId;

    SQSConnectionFactory customConnectionFactory =
        new SQSConnectionFactory(
            new ProviderConfiguration(),
            AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1).withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
        );

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory customJmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(this.customConnectionFactory);
    factory.setDestinationResolver(new CustomDynamicDestinationResolver(ownerAccountId));
    factory.setConcurrency(concurrency);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate customJmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(this.customConnectionFactory);
    jmsTemplate.setDestinationResolver(new CustomDynamicDestinationResolver(ownerAccountId));
    return jmsTemplate;
    }

    public static class CustomDynamicDestinationResolver implements DestinationResolver {

    private String ownerAccountId;

    public CustomDynamicDestinationResolver(String ownerAccountId) {
        this.ownerAccountId = ownerAccountId;
    }

    @Override
    public Destination resolveDestinationName(Session session, String destinationName, boolean pubSubDomain) throws JMSException {
        Assert.notNull(session, "Session must not be null");
        Assert.notNull(destinationName, "Destination name must not be null");
        if (pubSubDomain) {
        return resolveTopic(session, destinationName);
        } else {
        return resolveQueue(session, destinationName);
        }
    }

    protected Topic resolveTopic(Session session, String topicName) throws JMSException {
        return session.createTopic(topicName);
    }

    protected Queue resolveQueue(Session session, String queueName) throws JMSException {
        Queue queue;
        LOGGER.info("Getting destination for libraryOwnerAccountId: {}, queueName: {}", libraryOwnerAccountId, queueName);
        if (libraryOwnerAccountId != null && session instanceof SQSSession) {
        queue = ((SQSSession) session).createQueue(queueName, ownerAccountId);
        } else {
        queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
        }
        return queue;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Had to return to really old project to refresh memory about this :) But that's how I solved it too.

Comment: This worked for me as well as of Feb 2021! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just want to point out that there is no `libraryOwnerAccountId` in the code you shared. Most probably assuming this should be `ownerAccountId`

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on Akshay's response. I'm also using custom `DestinationResolver`. However my implementation doesn't need fixed `ownerAccountId`:

```
public class SqsDynamicDestinationResolver extends DynamicDestinationResolver {
  @Override
  protected Queue resolveQueue(Session session, String queueName) throws JMSException {
    if (session instanceof SQSSession) {
      SQSSession sqsSession = (SQSSession) session;
      String[] parts = queueName.split(":");
      if (parts.length == 2) {
        return sqsSession.createQueue(parts[1], parts[0]);
      }
    }

    return super.resolveQueue(session, queueName);
  }
```

The resolver is then set in `JmsTemplate` and `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory`.

You can either specify queue name simply as `"whatever_queue_name"` or with owner account id delimited with colon, for example `"0000216587:whatever_queue_name"`.

Please note, that **this solution will not work, if the `ownerAccountId` is from different region!** In that case you would need separate configurations.