# Invalid Address JMSException when using temporary credentials with SQSSession

Tags: spring-boot, jms, amazon-sqs

I am getting an error trying to connect to an SQS queue in another AWS account using JMS. I have tried to follow the approach taken in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104384/spring-boot-jmslistener-and-sqs-queues-on-different-accounts), but I am receiving the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: The address https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ is not valid for this endpoint. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 404; Error Code: InvalidAddress; Request ID: d7f72bd3-6240-5f63-b313-70c2d8978c14; Proxy: null)
```

Unlike in the post mentioned above (which I believe has the account credentials in the default provider chain?) I am trying to assume a role that has access to this SQS queue. Is this not possible through JMS or am I doing something incorrectly?

```java
import com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.ProviderConfiguration;
import com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSConnectionFactory;
import com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSSession;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenService;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClientBuilder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;

/**
 * A configuration class for JMS to poll an SQS queue
 * in another AWS account
 */
@Configuration
public class TranslationJmsConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TranslationJmsConfig.class);

    @Value("${iam.connection.arn}")
    private String connectionRoleArn;


    @Value("${account.id}")
    private String brokerAccountId;

    /**
     * JmsListenerContainerFactory bean for translation processing response queue
     *
     * @param concurrentConsumers number of concurrent consumers
     * @param maxConcurrentConsumers max number of concurrent consumers
     * @return An instance of JmsListenerContainerFactory
     */
    @Bean("translationJmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory translationJmsListenerContainerFactory(
            @Value("#{new Integer('${listener.concurrency}')}") int concurrentConsumers,
            @Value("#{new Integer('${listener.max.concurrency}')}") int maxConcurrentConsumers) {

        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
                new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

        factory.setConnectionFactory(getConnectionFactory(connectionRoleArn));
        factory.setDestinationResolver(new SqsDynamicDestinationResolver(brokerAccountId));
        factory.setSessionTransacted(false);    //SQS does not support transaction.
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE); // Automatic message acknowledgment after successful listener execution; best-effort redelivery in case of a user exception thrown as well as in case of other listener execution interruptions (such as the JVM dying).
        factory.setConcurrency(String.format("%d-%d", concurrentConsumers, maxConcurrentConsumers));
        return factory;
    }


    /**
     * create custom JMS Template
     * @return JmsTemplate
     */
    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate customJmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(getConnectionFactory(connectionRoleArn));
        jmsTemplate.setDestinationResolver(new SqsDynamicDestinationResolver(brokerAccountId));
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * A dynamic destination resolver for sqs queue
     */
    public class SqsDynamicDestinationResolver extends DynamicDestinationResolver {

        private final String brokerAccountId;

        /**
         * Constructor
         * @param brokerAccountId broker Account Id
         */
        public SqsDynamicDestinationResolver(String brokerAccountId) {
            this.brokerAccountId = brokerAccountId;
        }

        @Override
        protected Queue resolveQueue(Session session, String queueName) throws JMSException {
            if (session instanceof SQSSession) {
                SQSSession sqsSession = (SQSSession) session;
                return sqsSession.createQueue(queueName, brokerAccountId); // 404 invalid address -- Something wrong with creds?
                }
            return super.resolveQueue(session, queueName);
        }
    }

    private ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory(String connectionRoleArn){
        AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.builder()
                .build();

        // assume the connector account credentials -> so we can assume customer account using chaining
        AWSCredentialsProvider dummyCredentialProviders = IdentityHelpers.assumeInternalRole(stsClient, connectionRoleArn); // A helper that assumes temporary creds

        return new SQSConnectionFactory(
                        new ProviderConfiguration(),
                        AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                                .withCredentials(dummyCredentialProviders)
                );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that when using the temporary credentials, I didn't need the second parameter (the account id) of the `sqsSession.createQueue` call. so once i changed

```
sqsSession.createQueue(queueName, brokerAccountId);
```

To:

```
return sqsSession.createQueue(queueName);
```

it worked fine. I guess i missunderstood the need for the account id. I assume the parameter is used when you have multiple accounts in your providerChain and you want it to search a specific account? Any light on this would still be appreciated!